# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. while fitting the data in model

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to learn ML and got a data of  daily price of Sugar of few months. And will try to predict of up coming days. I have written following code till now.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
melted= pd.read_excel('melted.xlsx')
X = melted['Date'],['City']
y = melted['Rate']
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)
```

The last line is generating following error.

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Please suggest.

**EDIT 1**

I have converted the date column to numeric as below.

```
melted['Date']= pd.to_numeric(melted['Date'])
```

But it has come up with a new error

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

Comment: Should be - `X = melted[['Date','City']]`

Comment: It came up with following error. ```float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'```

Comment: This has to do with a different line - the fit (`model.fit(X,y)`). The DecisionTreeClassifier cannot fit on dates, it should probably be the index.

Comment: Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Am I using the right model?

Comment: I don't think that decision tree is the right ML algorithm since it is ignorant of date (i.e time series) data. Start here - https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-analysis-using-pandas-in-python-f726d87a97d8